# Django Media S3 - Model.get_queryset is accessing S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, django-storage, django-media

I have MEDIA files stored in `S3` bucket and I noticed that REST API responses are very slow. What I also noticed is that `Django` tries to access the `S3` when I do `Model.objects.all()`.

Why it does that? Doesn't it store the URL in the database so it doesn't have to access `S3` storage unless the `URL` is explicitly fetched (on the frontend side)?

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'project.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

The `image` field:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True, height_field='image_height',
                          width_field='image_width')
image_height = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
image_width = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure the query accesses the S3 or you have some sort of a serializer that does something with the file? Can you put a break point after the query and check if it hits to the S3?